# Video carousal using bootstrap for the first active item, how to do?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need help to fetch video dynamically using php mysql, 
i need help for indicator :

```
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
```

and class "active item"

following code i have used

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT aaa, ddd, fff, ggg FROM table ASC LIMIT 0, 20";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<h4>Upcoming Films:</h4>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$aaa=$row['aaa'];
$ddd=$row['ddd'];
$fff=$row['fff'];
$video=$row['video'];
?>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="item">
      <iframe width="750" height="422" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo"$video";?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

<?php
}
?>
  </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What did you try and what was wrong with that? What Error did you get?

Comment: @ToBe  i want to retrieve videos from db so need to display first item as active as per query in carousel and navigation for that such as data to slide should come dynamically... I mean i can do static but not using php.  So need help

Comment: Why not use a variable to see if it's the first one? Just increment it in your loop and echo your css class if 0.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel  something like this. I am not comfortable with php so kindly help me with an example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class=
                                      <?php
                                        echo '"';
                                        echo 'item '; 
                                        if ($i == 1) {
                                          echo 'active';
                                        }

                                        echo '"';

                                        ?>>
```

here goes content to loop

then

```
<?php

                                    $i++;


                                    }
  ?>
```